# How can I change Pelican Static Site Theme (on Windows dev Machine)?

Tags: pelican

I am not able to switch from the default theme. I am using powershell and running on Windows 7.

I generate and view with

```
.Scripts\pelican .\content
.Scripts\pelican --listen
```

Even `.Scripts\pelican -t 'notmyidea'` is not working

I have pelican-themes and pelican-plugins cloned into my project folder. Here are my configuration file content

publishconf.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- #
from __future__ import unicode_literals

# This file is only used if you use `make publish` or
# explicitly specify it as your config file.

import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.curdir)
from pelicanconf import *

# If your site is available via HTTPS, make sure SITEURL begins with https://
SITEURL = 'https://aself.com'
RELATIVE_URLS = False

FEED_ALL_ATOM = 'feeds/all.atom.xml'
CATEGORY_FEED_ATOM = 'feeds/{slug}.atom.xml'

DELETE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = True

# Following items are often useful when publishing

#DISQUS_SITENAME = ""
#GOOGLE_ANALYTICS = ""

THEME = "pelican-themes/blue-penguin"
# THEME = 'plumage'
# THEME = 'notmyidea'
LOAD_CONTENT_CACHE = False

PLUGINS_PATHS = ["plugins", "pelican-plugins"]
PLUGINS = ['assets','tipue_search']
TIPUE_SEARCH = True
# TEMPLATE_PAGES = {
#         'search.html': 'search.html',
#         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
THEME = "pelican-themes/blue-penguin"
```

to

```
THEME = "blue-penguin"
```

using the command

```
pelican-themes -l
```

will show you the installed themes you have